# how to run the dialogflow node js?

Tags: node.js, session, dialogflow-es

i am still confused about the documentation on Dialogflow nodejs, can I get clear for this? 
I have read the documentation this -> https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent

how to test my code and see the result of my query I input then ? 
should I do POST via Axios inside this functions

```
async function runSample(projectId = 'your-project-id') {
  // A unique identifier for the given session
  const sessionId = uuid.v4();

  // Create a new session
  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

  // The text query request.
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
        text: 'hello',
        // The language used by the client (en-US)
        languageCode: 'en-US',
      },
    },
  };

  // Send request and log result
  const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
  console.log('Detected intent');
  const result = responses[0].queryResult;
  console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
  console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
  if (result.intent) {
    console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
  }
}
```

i still not get clear for this, so do we need use HTTP request also in local to check this? 
I already follow the Dialogflow nodejs example, but what next?

it said on google we must POST to 
POST https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/{session=projects/*/agent/sessions/*}:detectIntent

nd the req body is on the request variable inside that functions, 
but I still not clear on dialogflow nodejs for the next step to run that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this directly using the express app. Just call this function from your express app route or you can call the given function in the file and use `node <filename.js>` to run the code. Make sure you add your google cloud credentials in the path name using `process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "<your_json_file_path>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(
    // below can be used to set the variable in code itself, if below is not working you can run following in the terminal
    //export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/<path of the json file"  
    {
      keyFilename: "/<path of the json file"
      
    }
);
```